# Can't delete a administrator file even though I am an administrator

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I accidentally created a VPN and now when I try and delete it, it just does nothing even though I press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. No matter what I do, I can't delete it and it's messing up my IP address since I'm trying to change it. When I run `ipconfig` in command prompt, all I get is the VPN status and IP showing up.

Comment: Boot in safe mode and try to delete the VPN

Answer (score 2):

I know it seems trivial but have you reset your computer? It's happened to me quite often, something won't completely change until I've reset. Not sure about VPNs specifically but it probably wouldn't hurt, right?

Perhaps it may also show in Network Connections? Try deleting it from there too. Just search Network Connections from Start. That may lead you to the same place zeldarulez sent you to, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's community support website](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/i-created-a-vpn-connection-and-it-worked-but-cant/1e283fc6-634b-4fd1-91c2-c51a1a78737f):

> Open network and sharing center. On left side click on Change adapter settings. You will get all created VPN connections, and you can delete what you don't need.

Comment: I did that already, and its just stuck there